# Начало изучения С++. Синтаксис

Tags: синтаксис, c++

Здравствуйте. Я новичок в с++). Овладеваю азами языка в Visual Studio, но иногда проблемы с которыми сталкиваюсь не могу решить. Обучение без учителя, в этом плане, довольно сложная штука. Буду очень признателен, если поможете ответить на несколько накопившихся вопросов.

1. Каким образом можно в функцию включить динамический массив?
2. В каком месте кода следует прописывать класс?
3. Почему при объявлении строковой переменной string надо использовать ^, а без неё не работает? при этом все остальные типы прописываются без этого.
4. Каким образом подключается библиотека?
5. Можно ли в проекте одновременно использовать 2 языка, например С++ и С#  ?

Comment: я вас, вероятно, удивлю, но если вы решили взяться за изучение C++, то вам именно на этом языке и стоит писать. А не на C++/CLI. Это [кое-что другое][1] 

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

Comment: купите книгу Керниган и Ритчи "*Язык Си*" вот с него и начните изучать, а потом какую нибудь по ++

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за советы... Куплю...

Answer (score 1):

Я в своё время начинал учить C++ по книге Джесса Либерти C++ за 24 часа (другое издание называется за 21 день). Там всё хорошо и понятно описано. Правда там есть только сам C++, стандартная библиотека почти не разбирается. Я выполнял все упражнения из книги, и всё прошло без проблем. А потом уже начал читать книги по OpenGL и WinAPI.

В чистом C++ нет динамических массивов, но их можно реализовать на нём, написав класс. Такой класс уже есть в стандартной библиотеке и называется std::vector.

Определить класс можно где угодно, но обычно все его объявляют в глобальной области видимости или пространстве имён (не в функции), причём до того, как он будет где-нибудь использован.

Значок ^ используется в `C++/CLI` для обозначения ссылок на управляемые классы, то есть классы, написанные под платформу .NET. `C++/CLI` - это мёртвый и непортируемый язык, который когда-то предназначался для портирования с C++ на C#. В общем никогда не пиши на нём, пиши на чистом ANSI C++.

По-разному. Для загрузки dll с сишным интерфейсом можно использовать LoadLibrary с GetProcAddress. Последний возвращает указатель на функцию по её имени. Второй метод, который годится для любых dll, а также статических библиотек, - это прописывание имени *.lib файла в списке подключаемых библиотек компоновщика. Также нужны заголовочные файлы, чтобы компилятор знал обо всех константах и функциях, который он вызывает. Но только этот метод также требует для dll наличия соответствующего ей файла .lib.

Если не использовать `C++/CLI`, то код на C++ должен экспортировать функции в dll, а код на C# их может использовать. Ещё можно как-то сделать взаимодействие через COM. Но напрямую код нельзя смешивать.

Comment: Тоже по Либерти начал знакомиться с плюсами и до сих пор не знаю ничего лучшего, что посоветовать новичку в плюсах.